# Why do I get no Output From my App Delegate File, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

why do I not get any Output in the Console for that Code:

```
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        ContentView().changeListe()
        print("called")
        return true
    }
}



@main
struct Order_Corner_V8App: App {
    
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var window: UIWindow?

    var body: some Scene {
        return WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that you can call this Code instead off a App Delegate Class in the UIKit Live Cycle...
Thanks Boothosh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the wrong delegate method. Check `launchOptions` parameter.
Use this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
     return true
 }
```